# Calculate magnetic field $B$ in a magnetized sheet parallel to $xy$ plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm having some trouble with this exercise:

> An infinite sheet of parallel faces with thickness $d$ is uniformly magnetized. Its magnetization is 10 A / m and forms an angle of 60º with the normal to the sheet. Calculate B inside and outside the sheet.

**Attempt**:

[image]

Firstly, I've calculated the magnetization vector $\vec{M}= \frac{M}{2}(0,\sqrt{3},1)$ in the figure's frame. Then I've obtained the current densities $\vec{J_m} = 0$ (as it is a constant magnetization) and $\vec{K_m}(z=0)=-\frac{\sqrt{M}}{2}M \vec{u_x}, \vec{K_m}(z=d)=+\frac{\sqrt{M}}{2}M \vec{u_x}$

Then I hesitate in calculating the magnetic field vector $\vec{B}$:

- If I apply the Ampère's Integral Form Law, as the total magnetic current is $0$, then I'd get $\vec{B}=0$.
- However, if I take the formula:
  $$\vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}(\int\int_S \frac{\vec{K_m}(z=0) \times \vec{R}}{R^3}da + \int\int_S \frac{\vec{K_m}(z=d) \times \vec{R}}{R^3}da)$$

my integral becomes divergent as the sheet is infinite and I have to take the limits of the integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. So, is $\vec{B}=0$? Why in the second case is it not possible to calculate the integral?

Comment: Your magnetization vector need to be multiplied by 10 (amps/m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrals are (conditionally) convergent.  To see this, Specifically, let the point we are evaluating the field be $(0,0,z)$, and let $(x', y', 0)$ be the coordinates of a current element on the sheet.  The contribution to the field from this element will be
$$
d \vec{B} = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \frac{(K \hat{x}) \times (z \hat{z} - x' \hat{x} - y' \hat{y})}{[z^2 + (x')^2 + (y')^2]^{3/2}} = -\frac{\mu_0 K}{4 \pi}  \frac{z \hat{y} + y' \hat{z}}{[z^2 + (x')^2 + (y')^2]^{3/2}}
$$
This must then be integrated over $x' \in (-\infty, \infty)$ and $y' \in (-\infty, \infty)$.

It is not hard to see that the $z$-component of $\vec{B}$,
$$
B_z = -\frac{\mu_0 K}{4 \pi} \iint \frac{y'}{[z^2 + (x')^2 + (y')^2]^{3/2}} \, dx' \, dy'
$$
will vanish when integrated over all $y'$, since it is an odd function of $y'$.  And the $y$-component of the integral,
$$
B_y = -\frac{\mu_0 K}{4 \pi} \iint \frac{z}{[z^2 + (x')^2 + (y')^2]^{3/2}} \, dx' \, dy'
$$
falls off sufficiently fast that the integral converges to a finite value.  (To actually perform this integral, it is easiest to switch to polar coordinates in the $x'y'$-plane.)

Strictly speaking, the integral for the $z$-component is *conditionally convergent*, and [the value of such an integral depends on how we take the limit as the region of integration goes to infinity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783575/is-there-a-rearrangement-theorem-for-conditionally-convergent-improper-integrals?rq=1)  The symmetry argument allows us to sidestep this by effectively choosing a "natural" way of taking the region of integration to infinity.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. So I have solved the integrals (which were not divergent at all) and I've got $B_y=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\mu_0M_0$ inside the region. So then, if we consider a region out of the sheet, $\vec{B}$ will be $0$, right?

Answer (score 1):

The magnetic dipole moment per unit volume associated with the y component of M should be the same as that which would be generated by two sheets of current (8.66 a/m) flowing in opposite directions on the surfaces of the magnetized sheet  (in the +x direction on top, and the -x direction on the bottom). Use those currents with Ampere's law to find $B_y$, and the angle to get B.